# Converter getting called on all button click

Tags: jsf, converters

I use JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 3.4.1

Following is my requirement

I have a h:selectOneMenu to populate list of users. The user is a mandatory field and I need to select the user and then click on the Submit button to pass on the user to the backing bean. I also have other buttons on the page. I have implemented a custom Converter to convert the selection to the corresponding User object model. The conversion should be done and the selected user should be submitted to the backing bean only when the Submit button is clicked.

But my Converter "techLeadConverter" method is called for all the button clicks and even when I click a menu item to navigate from the page.

How to restrict calling the Converter only on Submit button click

Following is my declaration

### XHTML page

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="technicalLeads" 
    value="#{resourceMB.technicalLead}" 
    converter="#{techLeadConverter}"
    required="#{not empty param[assignResource.clientId]}"
    requiredMessage="#{bundle.TechLeadMandatory}">

   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Technical Lead" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
   <f:selectItems value="#{resourceMB.technicalLeadList}" var="techLead"
      itemValue="#{techLead}"
      itemLabel="#{techLead.lastName}, #{techLead.firstName}">
   </f:selectItems>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put those buttons in a different form. Or, better, don't use command links/button for page-to-page navigation, but plain vanilla links/buttons.